# Node.js: callback values depending on each other

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Say I want to transform array with map function and each value is looked up in mongoDB with findOne, whose criteria in turn depends on current value from the array. To put it other way, simply transform array of ids to corresponding objects fetched from DB. Like:

```
arr.map(function(v) {
            collection.findOne({_id: v}, function(
                              ?
            });

            return {newField: ?};
});
```

Question marks are the places that need to be filled, but I guess the whole structure needs to be changed. Hopefully I'm clear.

I'm not used to such callback thinking and cannot wrap my head around it, am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async) library to perform an asynchronous [`map`](https://github.com/caolan/async#map), but in this case it would be easier and faster to use the [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in) operator to have MongoDB get them all in one go:

```
collection.find({_id: {$in: arr}}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    // docs contains the docs with the _id values that were in arr
});
```

Comment: Btw, how do you call that $in operator in JS? Is the $ sign somehow special? Or is it just arbitrary mongoDB name and it could be 'in' as well?

Comment: All the MongoDB operators start with $. But to JS it's just another character.

Answer (score 0):

I am not an expert in MongoDB, but what you can do is set a variable before the `collection` line, like this:

```
var return_element; var are_we_done = false;
collection.findOne({_id: v}, function(
  // assign value to return_element
  are_we_done = true;
)};
while (!are_we_done) {}
return {newField: <value of variable> };
```

Comment: I'm not expert an in JS neither, but I guess that way return_element will be returned uninitiated, since return is instantaneous and callback is not.

Comment: @meliniak I added some more code to make it synchrounous.

Comment: thanks for your input, but i'm pretty sure it's a bad idea since it blocks event loop, if the loop is stuck all users' requests are blocked as well.